# .gitignore doesn't work properly on Symfony 3 after composer update

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

I have two PC: A `laptop` and a `desktop computer`.
I was working two weeks on my Symfony 3 project with the desktop computer, and I defined some new parameters on my parameters.yml.dist

Today, I need to use my laptop, so I did a pull from my origin branch, and then I executed the following command to update my project:

```
php composer.phar update
```

This command updated successfully my project (parameters and vendor directory). With this, I can now run my project.

The problem is that now when I run:

```
git status
```

Lots of modified files appear in the `vendor` directory. Also `composer.lock`file apperars, and I think that this is correct, but not the vendor files.

My `.gitignore`contains, among others, the following line:
    `vendor/*`

What I did wrong? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably twofold.

You probably have checked in files from the vendor directory before adding it to the gitignore or maybe you accidentally added them with the `--force` flag which ignores the gitignore.

The other big problem is that you ran `composer update` this will not only install the dependencies in your composer.lock it will actually update them, meaning you might get different versions then the ones you were developing with before. Next time you should probably run `composer install` (even on a system where you already have vendors installed). This will do as advertised it will install all dependencies as defined in the composer.lock. Whenever you checkout a newer version of that file the install command will automatically update your local vendors to the versions defined there. This ensures that you always work with the same dependency versions.

Should you want to update your dependencies you might want to do it one by one using `composer update <dependency-name>` this will then again update your composer.lock which you should have checked into git.

In your case you might want to remove the vendor folder, but make sure you keep your composer.lock. Now you can commit this change to make sure you remove all checked in files vendor/. After that, your .gitignore should work again and running `composer install` should re-install everything as defined in the composer.lock and you should not see any changes in your work dir when running `git status`. If there are you might have to tweak your .gitignore, e.g. try `/vendor` instead of `vendor/*`.

Comment: Thanks, next time I will use `composer install`. For now, I restored previous composer.lock from GIT. I deleted my vendor folder, and I ran `composer install`. Seems to be ok. The only thing is that warning on the output: `Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies.`There are any way to restore also the composer.json file?

Comment: If you just restored it, you can do a simple trick to fix this: `composer update --lock`. This will only update the hash in your lock file, but not the dependencies. This usually works for me.

Comment: If you want to get more insight into how to work with composer you might want to watch: http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/composer (Disclaimer: I haven't watched it yet, but from the list of included topics it sounds interesting).